# How to implement NodeJS OAuth2 for an Angular App?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm trying to to implement the Resource Owner Password flow with a NodeJS API to authenticate my frontend Angular app.

I'm having problems how to implement how the user sends his credentials (username and password) to the API. [The flow I know](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) I'm used to send this body variables:

**Request body:**

```
grant_type: password
username: myusername
password: mypassword
client_id: frontendApp
```

Obs: I don't send the client_secret because It is not important, because It's an Angular app, so eveyone can see, but I created a seed client that represent my frontend client. I also created a flag that only this client (frontendApp) can authenticate without client_secret.

When I come to NodeJS I've been reading some tutorials about how to implement this flow in my API, and I notice that my knowledge of how the authentication flow must ocurs maybe is not a pattern.

I pick these tools to start building the security of the API: passport.js and oauth2orize.

According to the tutorials I do need to protect the token endpoint. I didn't catch the idea of why, because the user will access It to just authenticate, with the grant_type: password or grant_type: refresh_token, so he'll have to send me credentials like username and password in the first case or the refresh token in the second, so why do I need to use passport.js with basic and client password strategy?

Talking about Basic and Client Password strategy... Again according to the tutorials I should implement both, because the Basic strategy authenticates by header and the Client Passport strategy by body content. Here I see some ugly things.

Like I mentioned, I don't see reasons to protect the token endpoint, maybe I'm wrong, maybe exists some security problem that I didn't notice.

Another thing is because the Basic strategy and Client Password have different contexts, the first receive username and password and the second client_id and client_secret. When I want to get access and refresh token for the first time I must send all these things:

**Request body:**

```
grant_type: password
username: myusername
password: mypassword
client_id: frontendApp
client_secret: clientsecret

(or with the authentication in the header)
```

I wouldn't like to send the client_secret, at really nor client_id, but the client password strategy library makes me, and It is something very useless, because everyone can look my frontend code where It is stored, because of It I think It is not necessary to protect the token endpoint.

I'd like to send only the username and password, if the user is sending only username and password I already know that It is an frontend client trying to authenticate. I found an [explanation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) of how Resourse Owner Password should work, and It shows an example of request:

```
https://oauth.example.com/token?grant_type=password&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

It shows something like my older ASP.NET app, using username, password and client_id.

Does someone know if I should care about It or I can build It my-like mode, because the NodeJS implementations is not following the way I know.